# Gradle - The tests were not received

Tags: java, gradle, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I have tried making different projects, looked through dozens of threads but couldn't find anything that helped. Whenever I try to run my tests intellij/gradle returns something like "Test events were not received" or "No tests were found" depending on which button I click to run them.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
   }
   test {
        java {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
}

test { useJUnitPlatform() }
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

The SDK I use is Java 17, these are my gradle settings (the gradle version is 7.5)
[image]

I tried invalidating caches, restarting my ide, tried different gradle, JUnit and SDK versions but nothing seems to help.
My uni grades depend on me fixing this somehow, so if anyone knows whats going on, please let me know :(

Comment: can you add a screenshot of `Tests.java`

Comment: @Hendrik Hübner you don't need to list the `sourceSet` in the gradle file. You are following the default project layout pattern.

Comment: You can also check the `Tests` "Run configuration"